# select the bigger ball

Tags: python, algorithm, image, image-processing

I've got an array of data filled with "#" and "." for example it display something like this :

```
...........#############..............................
.........################..................#######....
........##################................#########...
.......####################..............###########..
........##################................#########...
.........################..................#######....
...........#############..............................
```

I want to create an algorithm that find the bigger ball and erase the smaller one.
I was thinking of using the longest sequence of "#" to know what is the diameter.

So i've got something like this :

```
x = 0
longest_line = 0
for i in range(0, nbLine) :
   for j in range(0, nbRaw) :
       if data[i, j] = red :
          x = x+1
          if data[i, j+1] != red:
```

And i don't know what to do next..

Comment: could you explain more about how you do to have balls like that? (no sexual jokes I promise)

Comment: What assumptions can you make? Will the balls always be centered?  Will they always be balls, or could they sometimes be irregular shapes?  How do you want to handle 2 balls of the same size?  Will the balls always have at least one space between them, or could they directly abut eachother?

Comment: It's by image processig, using PIL, everytime i've got something red, i print '#', and everything else is '.'

Comment: Should this question have a #homework tag?

Comment: You can say that, i'm just asking to improve,my algorithm, not cheat or anything

Answer (score 3):

I would use some sort of a [segmentation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_%28image_processing%29), and then simply count the number of pixels in each object. Then simply erase the smaller one, which should be easy as you have a tag of the object.

The segmentation algorithms typically work like this.

1. Perform a raster scan, starting upper left, working towards bottom right.
2. As you see a #, you know you have an object. Check it's neighbors.
3. If the neighbors have a previously assigned value, assign that value to it
4. If there there are multiple values, put that into some sort of a table, which after you are done processing, you will simplify.

So, for a very simple example:

```
...##...
.######.
...##...
```

Your processing will look like:

```
00011000
02111110
00011000
```

With a conversion such that:
2=>1

Apply the look up table, and all objects will be tagged with a 1 value. Then simply count the number of pixels, and you are done.

I'll leave the implementation to you;-)

Comment: how will this handle the case when there are circles next to each other (ie. without any "." in between) ?

Comment: @TejasP: It wouldn't work, unless you can do some sort of filtering that doesn't depend on position.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get your data into a nicer array structure
2. Perform [connected component labelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling)
3. Count the number of elements with each label (ignoring the background label)
4. Choose the label with the largest number of elements

Answer (score 2):

Do you olways have only 2 shapes like this? Because in this case, you could also use the python regular expression library. This code seems to do the trick for your example (I copied your little drawing in a file and named it "balls.txt"):

```
import re

f = open("balls.txt", "r")

for line in f :

   balls = re.search("(\.+)(#+)(\.+)(#*)(\.+)", line) 

   dots1 = balls.groups()[0]
   ball1 = balls.groups()[1]
   dots2 = balls.groups()[2]
   ball2 = balls.groups()[3]
   dots3 = balls.groups()[4]

   if len(ball1) < len(ball2): 
       ball1 = ball1.replace('#', '.')
   else:
       ball2 = ball2.replace('#', '.')

   print "%s%s%s%s%s" % (dots1, ball1, dots2, ball2, dots3)
```

And this is what I get:

```
...........#############..............................
.........################.............................
........##################............................
.......####################...........................
........##################............................
.........################.............................
...........#############..............................
```

I hope this can give you some ideas for the resolution of your problem

Comment: re is the name of the "regular expression" library of python. Basicaly, one can use it to search patterns in character strings. For instance, re.search("(\.+)(#+)(\.+)(#*)(\.+)", line) means "I'm looking for : some dots, one or more # symbols, then dots, then one or more # symbols, then some more dots in this line. Actually here is the link: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html
I hope it helps you a little bit :)

Comment: attributeError :'NonteType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: It seems like the re.search(..) didn't find anything (that's why it returned None). So my best guess is :
- You may have not used the same file
or 
- You have at least one extra line in the file that doesn't have anything writen in it
Try to replace :
 balls = re.search("(\.+)(#+)(\.+)(#*)(\.+)", line) 
with:
 balls = re.search("(\.*)(#*)(\.*)(#*)(\.*)", line)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the balls don't touch:

Assuming exactly two balls

Create two ball objects, (called balls 0 and 1) each owns a set of points.  Points are x,y pairs.

scan each row from top to bottom, left to right within each line.

When you see the first #, assign it to ball 0 (add it’s x,y cords to the set owned by the ball 0 object).

When you see any subsequent #, add it to ball 0 if it is adjacent to any point already in ball 0; otherwise add it to ball 1.  (If the new # is at x, y we just test (x+1,y) is in set, (x-1, y) is in set, (x, y+1) is in set, (x, y-1) is in set, and the diagonal neighbors)

When the scan is complete, the list sizes reveal the larger ball.  You then have a list of the points to be erased in the other ball’s points set.